# Functional Dependencies and Armstrong notation fundementals

Tags: normalization, relational-theory, dependencies

if AB -> C and B -> A does that mean B -> C?

B -> B is trivial and if we do composition with B->A, it becomes (B-> BA), then by transitivity does that mean B->C? but if B -> C is correct, it contradicts with the fact that B needs A to determines C

Comment: What does title have to do with the rest of the post & what is given & what exactly is the question? This is not clear. Why would or wouldn't the rules you name give what you say & why are you unsure? (Besides quoting the Armstrong axioms you use so you can explain & justify your reasoning, presentations differ on definitions, so it's good to give them for clarity.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on my 1st comment.